# Updating my current script which modifies multiple lines into a single one

Tags: autohotkey, clipboarddata

My current script copies text like this with a shortcut:

```
:WiltedFlower: aetheryxflower ─ 4
:Alcohol: alcohol ─ 3,709
:Ant: ant ─ 11,924
:Apple: apple ─ 15
:ArmpitHair: armpithair ─ 2
```

and pastes it modified into a single line

`Pls trade 4 aetheryxflower 3 alcohol 11 ant 15 apple 2 armpithair <@id>`

As you can see there are already two little problems, the first one is that it copies only the number/s before a comma if one existed instead of ignoring it. The second is that I always need to also copy before hitting the hotkey and start re/start the script, I've thought of modifying the script so that it uses the already selected text instead of the copied one so that I can bind it with a single hotkey.

That is my current script, it would be cool if anyone can also tell me what they used and why exactly, so that I also get better with ahk

```
!q::
list =
While pos := RegExMatch(Clipboard, "(\w*) ─ (\d*)", m, pos ? pos + StrLen(m) : 1)
 list .= m2 " " m1 " "
Clipboard := "", Clipboard := "Pls trade " list " <@951737931159187457>"
ClipWait, 0
If ErrorLevel
 MsgBox, 48, Error, An error occurred while waiting for the clipboard.
return
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of your copied text dont change, you can use something like this:

> #Persistent
>
> OnClipboardChange:
>
> ```
> list =
> a := StrSplit(StrReplace(Clipboard, "`r"), "`n")
> Loop,% a.Count() {
>     b := StrSplit( a[A_Index], ": " )
>     c := StrSplit( b[2], " - " )
>     list .= Trim( c[2] ) " " Trim( c[1] ) " "
> }
> Clipboard := "Pls trade " list " <@951737931159187457>"]
> ToolTip % Clipboard   ;   just for debug
> ```
>
> return

With your example text, the output will be:

> Pls trade  aetheryxflower ─ 4  alcohol ─ 3,709  ant ─ 11,924  apple ─ 15  armpithair ─ 2  <@951737931159187457>

And this will run EVERY TIME your clipboard changes, to avoid this, you can add at the top of the script #IfWinActive, WinTitle or #IfWinExist, WinTitle depending of your need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given would solve the problem, assuming that it never changes pattern as Diesson mentions.

I did the explanation of the code you provided with comments in the code below:

```
!q::
list = ; initalize a blank variable
 ; regexMatch(Haystack, regexNeedle, OutputVar, startPos)
 ; just for frame of reference in explanation of regexMatch

While ; loop while 'pos' <> 0 
pos := RegExMatch(Clipboard ; Haystack is the string to be searched, 
in this case the Clipboard

    , "(\w*) ─ (\d*)" ; regex needle in this case "capture word characters
(a-z OR A-Z OR 0-9 OR _) any number of times, space dash space
then capture any number of digits (0-9)"

    , m ; output var array base name, ie first capture will be in m1
second m2 and so on.

    , pos ? pos + StrLen(m) : 1) ; starting position for search
 "? :"used in this way is called a ternary operator, what is saying
is "if pos<>0 then length of string+pos is start position, otherwise
start at 1". Based on the docs, this shouldn't actually work well
since 'm' in this case should be left blank

 list .= m2 " " m1 " " ; append the results to the 'list' variable
followed with a space

Clipboard := "" ; clear the clipboard.

Clipboard := "Pls trade " list " <@951737931159187457>"

ClipWait, 0 ; wait zero seconds for the clipboard to change

If ErrorLevel ; if waiting zero seconds for the clipboard to change
doesn't work, give error msg to user.
 MsgBox, 48, Error, An error occurred while waiting for the clipboard.
return
```

Frankly this code is what I would call quick and dirty, and seems unlikely to work well all the time.